# Sequelize include with multiple where condition

Tags: include, sequelize.js, composite-primary-key

I have a bit of problem for using Sequelize with `include`. The problem is that my model uses two primary keys in child table.

So it goes like this 
Parent table
User : Id, ...
Post : Id, UserId(foreign key, binds to user id), ...
Post Hash Tag : HashTag, PostId(foreign key, binds to Post id), UserId(foreign key, binds to user id of Post table)

So the table hierarchy looks like this
user - post - post hash tag

Now when I try to do like this,

```
Post.findAll(
  include: {
    model: post hash tag
  }
)
```

then it only searches the post hash tags for where post id of post hash tag table is equal to post id of post table

So I added like this

```
Post.findAll(
  include: {
    model: post hash tag
    where: {
      col1: models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.col('POST.USER_ID'), '=', models.sequelize.col('POST_HASH_TAG.USER_ID'))
    }
  }
);
```

Then it will gives a problem at 'where' clause that Post.USER_ID cannot be found.

If I change col1 value to Post.userId then now it solves the above error but gives another error at 'on' clause

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

The full model is given here

User

```
sequelize.define('User', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey : true }
)
```

Post - I know multiple primary declaration is not working correctly, so don't bother to consider too much

```
sequelize.define('Post', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey: true },
    userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true }
)
```

Post hash tag

```
sequelize.define('PostHashTag', {
    postId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'POST_ID', primaryKey: true },
    hashTag: { type: DataTypes.STRING(20), field: 'HASH_TAG', primaryKey: true },
    userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true }
  }
)
```

and the query I used is

```
Post.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'userId'],
  where: {
    userId: userId,
    id: { $lt: postId }
  },
  include: [{
    model: models.PostHashTag,
    attributes: ['hashTag'],
    where: {
      col1: models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.col('Post.USER_ID'), '=', models.sequelize.col('PostHashTag.userId'))
  }]).then(...)
```

Comment: I found an answer by myself...
col1: models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.col('Post.USER_ID'), '=', models.sequelize.col('PostHashTag.userId'))
this should be
userId: models.sequelize.col('POST_HASH_TAG.USER_ID')
this will work. The physical names of table and column used in parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer by myself... col1:

```
models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.col('Post.USER_ID'), '=', models.sequelize.col('PostHashTag.userId'))
```

this should be

```
userId: models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.col('POST.userId'), '=', models.sequelize.col('POST_HASH_TAG.USER_ID'))
```

this will work. The physical names of table and column used in parenthesis